# Does Exchange 2013 have a pop3 connector like SBS 2011 did?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013, pop3

I'm looking at installing a server with exchange 2013 loaded. I have however just noticed that the current server has SBS 2011 and is using a pop3 connector to retrieve email hosted elsewhere. I don't think anything fundamental is changing so I would need a pop3 connector moving forward (I'm not a fan).

I have searched but can find nothing conclusive to say 2013 Exchange has or has not got a Pop3 connector. I believe it doesn't but was hoping someone who has experienced Exchange 2013 can give me a conclusive answer.

Comment: It doesn't. Why don't you just use the MX record to deliver email directly to the Exchange server?

Comment: Thank you for the information. Unfortunately the accounts are btconnect accounts and to that extent we have no control over the MX record. As an IT engineer myself I know this is in the Stone Age but my hands are tied so it is what it is.